# Sharing data between different step files within the same scenario

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

Given this simple senario

```
  Scenario: checkout the response code after foo data request 

    I request foo data
    Then the response code is 200
```

In my foo step file i write a step that make a api call :

```
   When(/^I request foo data$/, (callback) => {
        ...
        apiCall().then((response) => {
            ...
            this.responseStatus = response.statusCode;
            callback();
        })
    });
```

And in my common step file i want to put shared steps like :

```
Then(/^the response code is (\d+)$/, function (responseCode) {
    assert.equal(responseCode, this.responseStatus);
});
```

But the problem is when i try to run it I got :

`this` object is not shared apparently and I got :

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 200 == undefined
```

And if I move the code to the same file it work !

So how can I solve this issue with different files ?

Comment: Looks like your callback() in When step not resolving before execution moves to Then step. I have tried same use case using async and await and the data stored in When step to 'this' is able to access successfully in 'Then' step..

Comment: Try this way once: When(/^I request foo data$/, async function() => {
       let response = await apiCall().response();
        this.statuCode = response.statusCode;  })
    });

Answer (score 0):

One way we were doing this is to have a global variable that is accessible in both the files. Something like a constant which is initialized and then reassigned in your WHEN step. This can be utilized in your THEN file later.

Comment: I already did this, i am looking for something else

Comment: what do you mean something else?

Comment: Something built in cucumber

Comment: Maybe you should update your question with more details like what exactly you are looking for.